# Python lists memory allocation

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=a
a.sort()
```

what are the values of a and b now?
I am getting both a and b are same. But how to make it different

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: Yes, *because `a` and `b` are two variables that refer to the **same** object*. You did that yourself when you did `b = a`, that's what that means. As an aside, please tag all python related questions with the generic [python] tag.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to initialize b=[] and append all elements of a to b, one by one.

```
    a=[1,2,3,5,4] #Let's say
    b=[]
    for i in a:
        b.append(i)
    a.sort()
```

Now a and b will be different.

Comment: this is *one* way, but normally you woujld just do `b = a.copy()` or `b = a[:]` or even `b = list(a)`